# Wrong SQL update query generated on merge

Tags: java, sql-server, jpa, openjpa, websphere-7

When using EntityManager's merge method on WebSphere Application Server 7 with MS SQL Server 2008 to update entity in database, wrong SQL query being generated (no update parameters after SET keyword (see stacktrace below)).

Most likely this issue occurs when I'm trying to merge entity with no changes regarding DB, but this aint gettin me closer to solution.

Does anybody has a solution/workaround for this?

```
Caused by: <openjpa-1.2.4-SNAPSHOT-r422266:1481680 nonfatal general error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: Неправильный синтаксис около ключевого слова "WHERE". {prepstmnt 1814850604 UPDATE COMPANY_REF SET  WHERE ID = ? [params=(int) 11751]} [code=156, state=S0001]
FailedObject: ru.hostco.jpa.Company-11751
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.DBDictionary.narrow(DBDictionary.java:4315)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.DBDictionary.newStoreException(DBDictionary.java:4280)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SQLExceptions.getStore(SQLExceptions.java:102)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SQLExceptions.getStore(SQLExceptions.java:72)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.PreparedStatementManagerImpl.flushAndUpdate(PreparedStatementManagerImpl.java:132)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.PreparedStatementManagerImpl.flushInternal(PreparedStatementManagerImpl.java:90)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.PreparedStatementManagerImpl.flush(PreparedStatementManagerImpl.java:73)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.OperationOrderUpdateManager.flushPrimaryRow(OperationOrderUpdateManager.java:203)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.OperationOrderUpdateManager.flush(OperationOrderUpdateManager.java:89)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.AbstractUpdateManager.flush(AbstractUpdateManager.java:91)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.AbstractUpdateManager.flush(AbstractUpdateManager.java:74)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCStoreManager.flush(JDBCStoreManager.java:721)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingStoreManager.flush(DelegatingStoreManager.java:130)
    ... 51 more
```

---

### Edit 1

There is some code of entity entity and merging.

```
@Stateless
public class CompanyPersistanceManagerImpl implements CompanyPersistanceManager {

    private static Logger _logger = Logger
            .getLogger(CompanyPersistanceManagerImpl.class.getName());

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "ListGatewayJPA")
    private EntityManager entityManager;
    @EJB
    private SettingsPersistenceManager settingsPersistenceManager;

    ...

    @Override
    public Company updateCompany(Company company) {
        company = entityManager.merge(company);
        entityManager.flush();
        return company;
    }

    ...

}
```

---

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "COMPANY_REF")
@NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name = "getAllCompanies", query = "SELECT c FROM Company c ORDER BY c.name"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "getCompanyByName", query = "SELECT c FROM Company c WHERE c.name = :name"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "getCompanyByDeltaCode", query = "SELECT c FROM Company c WHERE c.code = :code"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "getCompanyById", query = "SELECT c FROM Company c WHERE c.id = :ID"), })
public class Company implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "INN")
    private String inn;

    @Column(name = "ENCODING")
    private String encoding;

    @Column(name = "CODE")
    private String code;

    @Column(name = "ACC", length = 20)
    private String acc;

    @Column(name = "FEE_ACC", length = 20)
    private String feeAcc;

    @Column(name = "WWA", length = 7)
    private String wwa;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "BENATTR_ID")
    @ForeignKey
    private Benattr benattr;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "COMPANY_TRANSFERTYPE_REL", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "COMPANY_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "TRANSFER_TYPE_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID") })
    private Set<TransferType> transferType;

    public static enum WWA_VALUES {
        NEVER, ALWAYS, REQUEST
    }

    @Transient
    private RGAORG info;

    @Transient
    private boolean selected = false;

    public Company() {
        super();
    }

    public String getAcc() {
        return acc;
    }

    public void setAcc(String acc) {
        this.acc = acc;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getInn() {
        return this.inn;
    }

    public void setInn(String inn) {
        this.inn = inn;
    }

    public String getEncoding() {
        return this.encoding;
    }

    public void setEncoding(String encoding) {
        this.encoding = encoding;
    }

    public Set<TransferType> getTransferType() {
        if (transferType == null) {
            transferType = new HashSet<TransferType>();
        }
        return transferType;
    }

    public void setTransferType(Set<TransferType> transferType) {
        this.transferType = transferType;
    }

    public TransferType[] getTransferTypeAsArray() {
        TransferType[] arr = null;
        if (transferType != null) {
            arr = new TransferType[transferType.size()];
            return transferType.toArray(arr);
        } else {
            arr = new TransferType[0];
            return arr;
        }

    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public RGAORG getInfo() {
        return info;
    }

    public void setInfo(RGAORG info) {
        this.info = info;
    }

    public boolean isSelected() {
        return selected;
    }

    public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
        this.selected = selected;
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see java.lang.Object#hashCode()
     */
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + id;
        return result;
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see java.lang.Object#equals(java.lang.Object)
     */
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!(obj instanceof Company)) {
            return false;
        }
        Company other = (Company) obj;
        if (id != other.id) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public String getFeeAcc() {
        return feeAcc;
    }

    public void setFeeAcc(String feeAcc) {
        this.feeAcc = feeAcc;
    }

    public String getWwa() {
        return wwa;
    }

    public void setWwa(String wwa) {
        this.wwa = wwa;
    }

    public Benattr getBenattr() {
        return benattr;
    }

    public void setBenattr(Benattr benattr) {
        this.benattr = benattr;
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you also show us, how you update the entity and how your entity looks like?

Comment: Thank you for reply. Requested information added to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you use the unstable 1.2.4-SNAPSHOT version of OpenJPA. I would downgrade it to 1.2.3 and see if the problem still occurs.

On the other side, I suppose the error occurs (please test that) only if OpenJPA does not have any fields to update. In this case, I would simply surround the code with an try-catch block, and ignore the error (you asked for a workaround).

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
Unfortunately same issue occurs when using openjpa-1.2.3-r422266.
Furthermore, there is a situation, when modified entity also doesn't merge correctly with exactly same symptoms.